# emacs: is there a way to specify a case-insensitive search in a regexp?

Tags: regex, emacs

In Javascript, I just need to append a `i` to the regexp to make it case-insensitive.  In .NET, I use a [`RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx).

I know about `case-fold-search`.  What I want is to specify that behavior in the regex itself, as specified in an elisp program. Possible?

Comment: I see you are a troublemaker!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As someone said earlier, the way to control this is to bind `case-fold-search`.  There is no way to specify the regex's case-sensitivity (or lack thereof) in the regex itself.

As it happens, regexp matching is already case-insensitive by default.

Comment: I do not know about `case-fold-search`.  Would you elaborate?  I tried `M-x customize-variable RET case-fold-search`; I set it to `nil`. But, this still seems to be ignoring case: `M-x search-forward-regexp RET ^[^^I]+^I[a-z]`.  Meanwhile, since almost eight years have passed, is there now a way to make an individual emacs regexp be case insensitive?

Comment: As far as I know, `case-fold-search` is still the only way to do it.  Try using `M-x set-variable RET` instead of `M-x customize-variable`, and ensure that you do so in the same buffer in which you're doing the search.